# Yadcf custom_func doesn't recognize column value with a radio button.

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10, yadcf

I am trying to use Yadcf with DataTables 1.10+. My situation is each row in my data table has a column with 4 radio buttons. I would like to be able to filter that data with Yadcf. I couldn't find any way to do this without utilizing a custom function.

```
yadcf.init(oTable, [
       // { column_number: 0 },
       // { column_number: 1 },
        {
            column_number: 2,
            filter_type: "text"
        },
        {
            column_number: 3,
            filter_type: "text"
        },
       // { column_number: 4 },
        {
            column_number: 5,
            filter_type: 'custom_func',
            custom_func: statusFilter,
            data: JSON.parse(jsonStatus)
```

You can see on column 5 i call a custom function called statusfilter

```
function statusFilter(filterVal, columnVal) {
    var found;

    if (columnVal === '') {
        alert('here');
        return true;
    }
}
```

it is passing the filterVal correctly but the columnVal is empty thus throwing my alert and returning.

I tried to look through the code a bit and see that yadcf sees the aData for column 5 has empty. I am not sure why.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make this work.

Thanks,

Comment: you might need to update datatables model upon selecting radio on that row, but without an example jsbin / jsfiddle I can't really help , you can modify the following jsbin http://jsbin.com/mexemavusu/edit?js,output

Comment: i updated that jsbin. http://jsbin.com/dudulapobe/edit?js,output it does pass a column value. Unfortunately it passes all the radio buttons as column values. I am guessing the reason mine is blank is because its loaded through Ajax, but this seems like  an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've added enhancement to [0.9.0.beta.11](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/5342cdded1e9274a152929dd884b5e0ddd04d976/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js), to the [custom_func](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/5342cdded1e9274a152929dd884b5e0ddd04d976/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L40) - 4'th argument - it holds the html DOM of the table row. see [jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/quzidijahi/1/edit?js,output) and inspect how I used it.

```
function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal, rowVal, stateVal) {
    if (columnVal === '') {
        return true;
    }

    if ($(stateVal[0]).filter(':checked').val() === filterVal) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The thing is that you have to find a way to update your DOM on mouse readio button selection so the filter will see the new value being *checked* - let me know how you did it eventually - maybe using jquery or updating datatables model